# How to support HTML to show emoji getting from DB setting from Mobile using angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, utf-8, utf-16

Scenario: We have a mobile app in which the User's name is editable. And developing a Angular web application to show user data.

The problem occurs when user adds emoji in their name using app but in website we are getting them as **`\\ud83d\\ude0e\\ud83d\\ude2f\\ud83d\\ude2`**, binding data in ng-bind.

Already added meta-tag `<meta charset="UTF-8">`.

Need help to resolve this issue.

HTML Code

```
<span class="user-name" ng-bind="feed.profileDisplayName"></span>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why there are two `angular` tags? What version are you actually using?

Comment: Using 1.5.5 version.

Comment: The last item in the string has only 3 hex digits `\\ude2`. Is that a typo?

Comment: this is how I am getting from databse

Comment: alright.. but the issues is I am not able to see emoji of this Unicode. It is displaying as it is in html.

Comment: The first two emojis  are encoded in UTF-16. The last one is  invalid. You should change the server side code to encode those characters properly in UTF-8.

Comment: I am able to see emoji on mobile app correctly. It also fetching data from same DB.

Comment: What are you getting from the database?!? Can you show it as bytes? (CAST name  AS BINARY, maybe). Does it really contain double (or even single) back-slashes?

Answer (score 0):

One can use [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) to convert it:

```js
var x="\\ud83d\\ude0e\\ud83d\\ude2f";
console.log(x);
eval("y=\""+x+"\"");
console.log("y=",y);
```